# How do I install an old version of a package?

Tags: 14.04, 10.04, downgrade

I played a game called SuperTuxKart (and still do) when I had Ubuntu 10.04 installed. The version was 0.6.2. Now I am on Ubuntu 14.04, and I have SuperTuxKart 0.8.1 installed. I was wondering if there was a way I could install version 0.6.2 of SuperTuxKart on 14.04? I have a couple of (3) SuperTuxKart 0.6.2 packages, but I can't figure out how to install them.

Comment: If you solved it your self, then add solution as an answer. Then except the answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install the package by installing some lucid packages ([this](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/supertuxkart/supertuxkart_0.6.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) and [this](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/supertuxkart/supertuxkart-data_0.6.2+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_all.deb)) after removing the 0.8.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you should remove the v0.81 package,then you can install v0.62 package.

1. To remove v0.81package. Using `apt-get remove SuperTuxKart`.
2. To install v0.62 package， you can run `apt-get install SuperTuxKart=0.62`. If your package is deb package，you should run `dpkg -i packagename`.

Good luck！

Comment: I tried that, but that version is not available in my repositories, and I don't know how to add it. I found a package that may be able to help me, though.

Comment: I do not know which repository should be used. But if you find a remote repo which has your package, you add it to `/etc/apt/source.list`.And run `apt-get update`. Try install.